# Best way to store time series in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table in my database that stores event totals, something like:

```
event1_count
event2_count
event3_count
```

I would like to transition from these simple aggregates to more of a time series, so the user can see on which days these events actually happened (like how Stack Overflow shows daily reputation gains).

Elsewhere in my system I already did this by creating a separate table with one record for each daily value - then, in order to collect a time series you end up with a huge database table and the need to query 10s or 100s of records. It works but I'm not convinced that it's the best way.

What is the best way of storing these individual events along with their dates so I can do a daily plot for any of my users?

Answer (score 0):

When building tables like this, the real key is having effective indexes. Test your queries with the `EXAMINE` statement or the equivalent in your database of choice.

If you want to build summary tables you can query, build a view that represents the query, or roll the daily results into a new table on a regular schedule. Often summary tables are the best way to go as they are quick to query.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement this is to use [Redis](http://redis.io). If you haven't worked before with Redis I suggest you to start. You will be surprised how fast this can get :). The way I would do such a thing is to use the Hash data structure Redis provides. Just assign every user to his Hash (making a unique key for every user like `"user:23:counters"`). Inside this Hash you can store a daily timestamp as `"05/06/2011"` as the field and increment its counter every time an event happens or whatever you want to do with that!

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be this thread. It has a simple, beginner level solution. [Time Series Starter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002903/efficiently-storing-time-series-data-mysql-or-flat-files-many-tables-or-files). If you are ok with rails models: This is a way it could work. For a sol called "irregular" time series. So this is a event here and there, but not in a regular interval. Like a sensor that sends data when your door is opened.

The other thing, and that is what I was looking for in this thread is regular time series db: Values come at a interval. Say 60/minute aka 1 per second for example a temperature sensor. This all boils down to datasets with "buckets" as you are suspecting right: A time series table gets long, indexes suck at a point etc. Here is one "bucket" approach [using postgres arrays](https://grisha.org/blog/2015/09/23/storing-time-series-in-postgresql-efficiently/) that would a be feasible idea.

Its not done as "plug and play" as far as I researched the web.